# Weird redirection to another site

Tags: redirects, iframe

I am using a government web site (in Spain) to carry out some stuff. As soon as I navigate into one of the screens, I am redirected to oracle.com. I see the original Spanish government web page for a fraction of a second, and then I am sent to Oracle.

I have contacted their technical support and they seem to have no clue of what is going on. I have done some googling and there seems to be a few reported scenarios of weird redirections like this due to IFRAME targets not being properly interpreted by the browser. I have recently updated to IE11, so the issue *might* be that the government web site that I am trying to use contains an IFRAME targetting Oracle, and IE11 is misinterpreting that as a redirect, or something like that.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any evidence of this actually happening? If so, can you please provide any pointers to technical help on how to fix it?
2. Is there any way that I can fix the issue so that I can keep using the government web site without the friggin' redirection? Please bear in mind that I have no access to the server; this would need to be a client-side hack.

Thanks.

*Edit*. I have tried using Google Chrome and the issue does not happen, so it must be an IE11 thing. This basically means that my problem is solved, since I can use Chrome to complete my business. Still, I'd love to know why the issue occurs with IE11.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Comment: @JohnConde: Thanks; I didn't realise that. Is there a way to migrate my question to Web Applications SE?

Comment: I don't think this would be on-topic for that website.

Comment: @JohnConde: Why not? This is what the Help Centre here says: "If the question is about another site (such as Gmail or Facebook) and not about your own website, it is off-topic here. Web Applications would be a better place to ask". When I check out the Help Centre at Web Applications, I can't find anything that would suggest this question would be off-topic. Care to clarify? Thanks.

Comment: That website isn't an application. Web Apps is geared towards using applications such as Gmail, Google Docs, etc. However, you can post in their [meta](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/) and link to this question to see if they would consider it to be on-topic. If they say it is I will definitely move it for you.

Comment: @JohnConde: I see. Now that I've read their help pages more closely, I have realised that they also tend to avoid programming-oriented questions, so maybe my discussion of IFRAMES is too technical. I'll ask in meta as you suggest and I'll get back to you depending on the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @CesarGon: I wouldn't say "IFRAMES is too technical", it just depends whether it is "on-topic". For instance, there are numerous programming related questions on WebApps that relate specifically to Google Spreadsheet/Drive - a Web Application - these appear to be on topic and are highly technical.

Comment: @w3d: Okay. I have posted a question on their meta (http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/is-this-question-on-topic); we'll see what they say.

Comment: @CesarGon: Just addressing your question... Have you tried IE11 compatibility mode? Have you tried another browser?

Comment: @w3d: Indeed, Chrome works OK, but IE11 in compat mode still fails. I have updated my question to show this.